# How to use output of SUM in new column?

Tags: sql, sum

My table looks like this:

```
Ride_distance    Ride_type
100              A         
50               B        
25               B       
25               C           
10               C          
40               A         
...              ...
```

Now I want to SUM all distances per type and display them like this:

```
Tot_Type_A  Tot_Type_B  Tot_Type_C
140         75          35
```

---

How can I do it?

Comment: Do you need them in the same row, or three separate rows would work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start with group by:

```
SELECT SUM(Ride_distance),Ride_type FROM rides GROUP BY Ride_type
```

If you must have them in the same row, use [pivot](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410.aspx):

```
SELECT 'TotalRide' as Total_Ride_Length, [A], [B], [C]
FROM
(SELECT Ride_distance, Ride_type FROM rides) AS SourceTable
PIVOT (
    SUM(Ride_distance) FOR Ride_type IN ([A], [B], [C])
) AS PivotTable;
```

Answer (score 3):

```
  SELECT SUM(Ride_distance), Ride_type
    FROM your_table
GROUP BY Ride_type
```

Comment: Gives the right information in the wrong format.  OP asked for it to be pivotted.

Comment: @Dems - I saw this, but I don't see the sense of pivotting here. I mean you have the same information, why bother to create additional work?

Comment: Then ask for context.  There may be a reason that you may or may not be able to refute.  But as-is, this only partially address what the OP asked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible, but you have to write a `case` statement for each type:

```
select 
 sum(case ride_type when 'A' then ride_distance else 0 end) as tot_type_A,
 sum(case ride_type when 'B' then ride_distance else 0 end) as tot_type_B,
 sum(case ride_type when 'C' then ride_distance else 0 end) as tot_type_C
from your_table
```

Comment: this solves my problem partially: I still end up with three rows.

Comment: @jorrebor I fixed the query, it's even simpler now, and it's probably very efficient also.

Answer (score 0):

Using `PIVOT`;

```
select 
    A as Tot_Type_A,
    B as Tot_Type_B,
    C as Tot_Type_C
from 
    dbo.the_table
pivot (
    sum(Ride_distance) for Ride_type in ([A],[B],[C])
) pvt
```